# Get all permissions during app installation on targeting API 26

Tags: android, android-webview, android-permissions, android-security

In Android API version 22 and before, system will get all permission while installation. From API 23(Marshmallow), system asks for permission during runtime(when the app actually tries to use a feature). This is not working out very well for some of the reasons.

- Developer has to write 2 different(1 - if user grants permission, 2.
  if user denied the permission) flows of code all the time.
- While requesting permission, Android has the full control to show what is the text to be displayed on the permission dialog and asks user to press Yes or No. Sometimes, the text displayed on the permission dialog is inappropriate.
- When we request more than one permission and if one of the permission is denied, app crashes due to Android code bug. This is an issue with API 23, 24 and 25. I think its fixed in 26.

Issues faced in our app,

Example 1 : For security reasons, we are trying to get device id but when we request permission, Android shows message like '**Allow MyApp to manage phone calls**'. We have nothing to do with phone calls, the message is inappropriate to access device id. This drops user registrations(sign-up) on the app and marketing team is highly worried.

Example 2: We have lot of web views and we try to use the offline storage and cache as much as possible for better user experience, but users are denying the permission because, Android permission dialog shows '**Allow MyApp to access storage files**'.

So, the question is, **Is there anyway to get all the permissions during app installation itself(like API v22 and before) on the newer API versions(23 and above) rather than requesting during run-time?**

Comment: An additional dialog can be shown education users why such permissions are needed. Alternatively(i feel bad when using such apps) you can take users to permission screen and have them enable all permissions. Or one more way(i personally do not install such apps) target 22 or less,

Answer (score 3):

First, request permission runtime is best-practice and this is the explanation from Google

> In some circumstances, you might want to help the user understand why your app needs a permission. For example, if a user launches a photography app, the user probably won't be surprised that the app asks for permission to use the camera, but the user might not understand why the app wants access to the user's location or contacts. Before you request a permission, you should consider providing an explanation to the user. Keep in mind that you don't want to overwhelm the user with explanations; if you provide too many explanations, the user might find the app frustrating and remove it.
>
> One approach you might use is to provide an explanation only if the user has already turned down that permission request. If a user keeps trying to use functionality that requires a permission, but keeps turning down the permission request, that probably shows that the user doesn't understand why the app needs the permission to provide that functionality. In a situation like that, it's probably a good idea to show an explanation.
>
> To help find situations where the user might need an explanation, Android provides a utiltity method, shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(). This method returns true if the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied the request.
>
> > Note: If the user turned down the permission request in the past and chose the Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog, this method returns false. The method also returns false if a device policy prohibits the app from having that permission.

So, in your situatation, if you read the documetation carefully, you could ask all permission one time in installation time. In your `build.gradle` file (App), set `targetSdkVersion` to api level lower than 23. For instance:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vn.yourpackage.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

}

Comment: I agree with best practice and google explanation.. the reality is when an app desperately requires a permission and users are denying, we have to work around to handle such scenario is frustrating..

Comment: If user is trying to deny, why you have to force them?

Answer (score 3):

> When we request more than one permission and if one of the permission
>   is denied, app crashes due to Android code bug.

This is not true. Your app has to be able to handle this situation.

> Is there any way to get all the permissions during app installation
>   itself(like API v22 and before) on the newer API versions(23 and
>   above) rather than requesting during run-time?

No, when your app targets API>=23 then you have to request permissions at run time.

As for the first example, I suggest you read the official [Best Practices for App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-permissions.html) documentation. It suggests a [useful tip](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-permissions.html#c_determine_the_device_your_instance_is_running_on) which may help you.

Regarding the second example, the best you can do is to explain the user why the app needs permissions. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request).